# Extending express app.get method in a nodejs app

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to extend the **app.get** behavior but it seems that after doing it, the app losses some configuration I did before extending it.

In the following snippet the **/sample** and **/es/sample** output are **empty** and the expected output should be **'value'**

Am I doing something wrong?

```
var app = require('express')();

app.set('myprop', 'value');

var _get = app['get'];

app['get'] = function (route, middleware, callback) {
    _get.call(app, route, middleware, callback);

    // For instance: I generate a new route for 'es' language.
    _get.call(app, '/es' + route, middleware, callback);
};

app.get('/sample', function(req, res){
    res.send(app.get('myprop'));
});

app.use(app.router);
app.listen(3000);
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I will answer myself...

I missed the following first line in the extension method :)

```
if (middleware === undefined && callback === undefined) return _get.call(app, route);
```

now it works like a charm!

```
app['get'] = function (route, middleware, callback) {
    if (middleware === undefined && callback === undefined) return _get.call(app, route);
    _get.call(app, route, middleware, callback);

    // For instance: I generate a new route for 'es' language.
    _get.call(app, '/es' + route, middleware, callback);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are broke `app.get` behaviour with one argument. Try this:

```
var app = require('express')();

app.set('myprop', 'value');

var _get = app['get'];

app['get'] = function (route, middleware, callback) {
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
        _get.call(app, route, middleware, callback);

        // For instance: I generate a new route for 'es' language.
        _get.call(app, '/es' + route, middleware, callback);
    } else {
        return _get.apply(app, arguments);
    }
};

app.get('/sample', function(req, res){
    res.send(app.get('myprop'));
});

app.use(app.router);
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim! I figured out after writing the question :) I've also updated my question with the solution but yours is much better.

Comment: just out of interest... what is this line all about `app.listen(3131);vadim@zapp:~/workspace/test$ cat ./ex.js` ??

Comment: @Val, this is copy/paste duplication. Fixed. Thanks.